# Add file to classpath of testcontainer in VS Code / Metals using build.sbt

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, testcontainers, sbt-native-packager, scala-metals

I have an sbt project configured with a `build.sbt`. When I run tests, a docker container is started with a configuration file available. This is how I wanted to use it in the test (https://www.testcontainers.org/features/files/#volume-mapping):

```
MyContainer.withClasspathResourceMapping(
    "/myConfigPath/configFile.config",
    "/myConfigPath/configFile.config",
    BindMode.READ_ONLY
  )
```

For that, I added the configuration file in `build.sbt` to the jar for tests like this:

```
.settings(
    Test / packageBin / mappings ++= Seq(
        (rootBaseDir.value / "myConfigPath" / "myFile.config") -> "/myConfigPath/configFile.config"
    )
```

When I run the test from my terminal with sbt it works, but when I run the test from the Metals's Test Explorer from within VS Code, the following error occurs:

```
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource with path /myConfigPath/configFile.config could not be found on any of these classloaders: [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@277050dc]
```

I also tried to add the file (folder) with `unmanagedClasspath` like this:

```
Test / unmanagedClasspath += rootBaseDir.value / "myConfigPath"
```

But the same error occurred.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this correctly?

Comment: If you add `myConfigPath` to the unmanaged classpath, my guess is that those files would be available as `/configFile.config` instead.

Comment: I have no experience with Scala, SBT or Test Explorer, but I am very confident this problem is unrelated to Testcontainers and explicitly about the classpath. So you can focus your search for a solution to this area.